# Slidingdrawer with FragmentActivity On Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingdrawer

I created an app with using fragmentactivity and alot of fragments....

Slddingdriwer's layout has attached on MainLayout. I open it from FragmentActivity class. 
it opens but I cant see any animation. How Should I do to see its animation??

Has anyone use it this like??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use [animateOpen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html#animateOpen%28%29) to open the SlidingDrawer? The regular `open()` method will just open the SlidingDrawer without animating it.